# Wrap C-style files in C++ stream

Tags: c++, iostream

For a project I MUST read/write using a C-style file type. It could be regular FILE, or a C version of gzfile, etc. I'd still like the convenience of using C++ streams. Is there a stream class that redirects to C-style file operations internally? So `myfile << hex << myint` eventually becomes `fprintf("%a", myint)` or something similar?

Answer (score 3):

What you need is an implementation of the `streambuf` class that writes on a C file. If there isn't already one in the C++ standard (which would disappoint me a bit, but not surprise me), you can make one and override the right methods.

Note that it will never translate `<<` as `fprintf(file, ...)`: the result will be more akin to `sprintf(buf, ...); fwrite(file, buf)`.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a standard one, but if you MUST do this then you'll have to use something non-standard.

GCC's standard library includes a streambuf type, `__gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf`, which can be constructed with a `FILE*` (or a file descriptor), which you can use to replace the streambuf of an `fstream`, or just use with a plain `iostream`  e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ext/stdio_filebuf.h>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    FILE* f = fopen("test.out", "a+");
    if (!f)
    {
        perror("fopen");
        return 1;
    }
    __gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf<char> fbuf(f, std::ios::in|std::ios::out|std::ios::app);
    std::iostream fs(&fbuf);
    fs << "Test\n";
    fs << std::flush;
    fclose(f);
}
```

Things to note about this:

- the `stdio_filebuf` must not go out of scope while the `iostream` is still referring to it
- you need to manually close the `FILE*`, the `stdio_filebuf` won't do that when constructed from a `FILE*`
- be sure to flush the stream before closing the `FILE*`, otherwise there could be unwritten data sitting in the `stdio_filebuf`'s buffer that cannot be written out after the `FILE*` is closed.

Comment: In your current code sample, fclose() will be called before the stream and buffer's destructors. Even if flushed first, this may be an undefined behavior: You should add a `{}`  block that ends before the call to fclose().

Comment: @Medinoc This is a library extension. Check the source code. I'd hazard a guess Jonathan, being a libstdc++ author, knows how to use its extensions `;-)`.

Comment: Well it's a long time since I've used those classes so I might have got it wrong. Medinoc's advice is a good idea, although I'm pretty sure it's not going to result in undefined behaviour, you just might lose data and `errno` will get set